# Does this limit converge? Can the exact value be found?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k+\ln(k+1)+C}-\ln n\right),$$

where $C$ is a given constant. Obviously this sequence is decreasing, but I can't estimate its lower bound very well.
Does this limit converge? If so, can the exact value be found? If not, can a better lower bound be given?

Comment: Did you try any inequality for $\log(k+1)$ ?

Comment: Did you look at the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant article? It and related work on the euler-Mascheroni constant might have some answers.

Comment: One can estimate $k + \ln(k+1) < k^{1+\varepsilon}$ for sufficiently large $k$, which gives a convergent sum with Riemann zeta function but the $\ln(n)$ makes it diverge, so this kind of estimate is not good enough to decide on the convergence.